# Android Clear Image Memory Cache on exit

Tags: android, image, gridview, memcached

I would like my app to clear image cache on exit. I cant figure out how do i call my clearcache() from my image loader activity. I'm getting an error "`No enclosing instance of the type MainGridViewImageLoader is accessible in scope`".  Could somebody please guide me how it is done? Below are my codes, i've marked those areas with comments.

MainPageActivity.class

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                           startActivity(intent);

                           MainGridViewImageLoader.this.clearCache(); //<<"No enclosing instance of the type MainGridViewImageLoader is accessible in scope"
                               System.exit(0);
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

    }
```

MainGridViewImageLoader.class

```
public class MainGridViewImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public MainGridViewImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

   final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_image;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          else
              photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the below codes clear my image memory cache?

```
public void clearApplicationData() 
         {
             File cache = getCacheDir();
             File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
             if (appDir.exists()) {
                 String[] children = appDir.list();
                 for (String s : children) {
                     if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                         deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) 
         {
             if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                 String[] children = dir.list();
                 for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                     boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                     if (!success) {
                         return false;
                     }
                 }
             }
             return dir.delete();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to access MainGridViewImageLoader by `MainGridViewImageLoader.this`.
It would only work if your MainPageActivity was an inner class of MainGridViewImageLoader, which it obviously isn't.

You should use a normal reference to MainGridViewImageLoader object. There probably is some place where you do `MainGridViewImageLoader loader = new MainGridViewImageLoader()`. Use that variable instead of `MainGridViewImageLoader.this`